# Error while installing python setuptools for compiling pyOpenSSL

Tags: python

I want to use pyOpenSSL, which I have downloaded and tried to build, but I am having problems with setuptools.
First I have downloaded [just python](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.6/) and used it with no success, but now I have tried with WinPython and got the same result, which is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 11, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup
  File "C:\Users\User\Downloads\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.3\python-2.7.6\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init_
_.py", line 11, in <module>
    from setuptools.extension import Extension
  File "C:\Users\User\Downloads\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.3\python-2.7.6\lib\site-packages\setuptools\extensi
on.py", line 5, in <module>
    from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
  File "C:\Users\User\Downloads\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.3\python-2.7.6\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py
", line 15, in <module>
    from setuptools.compat import numeric_types, basestring
  File "C:\Users\User\Downloads\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.3\python-2.7.6\lib\site-packages\setuptools\compat.
py", line 19, in <module>
    from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
  File "C:\Users\User\Downloads\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.3\python-2.7.6\lib\SimpleHTTPServer.py", line 27, i
n <module>
    class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
  File "C:\Users\User\Downloads\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.3\python-2.7.6\lib\SimpleHTTPServer.py", line 208,
in SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
    mimetypes.init() # try to read system mime.types
  File "C:\Users\User\Downloads\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.3\python-2.7.6\lib\mimetypes.py", line 358, in init

    db.read_windows_registry()
  File "C:\Users\User\Downloads\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.3\python-2.7.6\lib\mimetypes.py", line 260, in read
_windows_registry
    with _winreg.OpenKey(hkcr, subkeyname) as subkey:
TypeError: must be string without null bytes or None, not str
```

I have installed Python 2.7.6 with PyCharm with no success, and also tried WinPython with the same result.
I am running windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are facing problem in installing setuptools itself, you can download the windows binary file for setuptools from [this](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#setuptools) link.
This website is a great repository of pre-compiled windows binaries for various Python modules.

If installing 64-bit Python is not a necessity, I would suggest you to install 32-bit version of Python and other modules.

Comment: Annoyingly the link provided no longer has windows installers (binaries) and now uses .WHL files instead

Answer (score 1):

This is related to a bug in Python 2.7.6, to do with Windows Registry corruption.

Some programs (wrongly) write a terminating null to registry entries and this screws up setuptools.  Updating Python fixes the issue.

See [This blog post](http://www.swarley.me.uk/blog/2014/04/23/python-pip-and-windows-registry-corruption/)